# Using regular bluetooth to write data from one iOS device to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, bluetooth

I have been using CoreBlueTooth API in my application to write data from one iOS device to another. Now, as per BTLE specs and CoreBlueTooth framework, for every write request, peripheral has to respond back success/error in 10 seconds else framework returns a default error back.

As per my app implementation, I have to wait for some user action to return success/error.

Is there any regular BlueTooth framework (non-BTLW) which supports the write operation but do not put a stringent response timeout of 10 seconds? Please share the details.

Comment: Have you tried GameKit, and its peer-to-peer Bluetooth communication? You can connect devices using this without relying on Bluetooth LE.

Comment: No I did not. Could you please share some documentation/video/sample project links.

Comment: Apple has plenty of documentation on Game Kit, as well as videos from several sessions on it from WWDC. In addition to that, I have some notes on the subject (and sample code) from a course I taught a few years ago: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Fall2010CourseNotes/networking.html